# createConfigurationContext is not working

Tags: android, android-api-levels, android-configchanges

I want to change my app language , this is a code I've for supporting different api versions

```
val config: Configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration()
    val locale = Locale(getDefaultLang())
    val res: Resources = context.getResources()
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
        config.setLocale(locale)
    } else {
        config.locale = locale
    }
    val dm = res.displayMetrics
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        context.createConfigurationContext(config);
    } else {
        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config,dm);
    }
```

the problem is , on api 23 and above , it goes into this line :

```
context.createConfigurationContext(config);
```

but it doesn't effect the app and I should use this line to make it works

```
res.updateConfiguration(config, dm)
```

as you know , update configuration is depreciated

how to fix this ?

Comment: Hi Navid, did you find a solution for this?